# how to generate a floating point random number with two precision in python

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a floating point random number with two precision.
For example:2.54
How to change the `uniform(a,b)` in python.
Thanks

Comment: You are confusing `fixed point` with `floating point` you can't generate floating point numbers with a precision of 2 decimal places. (though you can print them to 2 decimal places). If you require 2 decimals places look at the `Decimal` type in the `decimal` module.

Comment: You can do it in a hacky way generating 3 digit random number and dividing it by 100

Comment: I'm not totally sure if you want two decimals, or randmon between two values? maybe you can clarify a little

Comment: @ArunG, how would be that? Could I see if you don't mind, I didn't follow you sorry

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use round function with uniform function to limit float number to two decimal places.

Example:

```
 round(random.uniform(1.5, 1.9),2)
 Out[]: 1.62

 round(random.uniform(1.5, 1.9),3)
 Out[]: 1.885
```

Comment: Thank you! And what should I do If I want to generate it fixed whenever I run my program?

Comment: if you want fixed number then just apply round(any_number,2). random.uniform will generate different value every time.

Answer (score 4):

This could be the possible solution, As requested by @Damian

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> randint(100, 999)/100.00
7.32
>>> randint(100, 999)/100.00
4.69
>>> randint(100, 999)/100.00
5.36
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate a random number between two numbers, with a specific amount of decimals, here is a way:

```
import random

greaterThan = float(1)
lessThan = float(4)
digits = int(2)

rounded_number = round(random.uniform(greaterThan, lessThan), digits)
```

in this case, your random number will be between 1 and 4, with two digits